# null exception when writing file to internal storage from separate class

Tags: android

I have two activities that I want to call the time class bellow but every time i call that class it throws up an exception. But if i put the `timeWrite()` method in the Activity it works well but if I put it in the time class and then try to call it to write the file it throws up exception.

```
public class time extends AlphabetActivity{
      private int time;
      public void timeWrite(int time) {

       try {
          String timeVal = String.valueOf(time);
          FileOutputStream timeStream = openFileOutput("time_file.txt",    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        timeStream.write(timeVal.getBytes());}
        timeStream.close();
       catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}}
```

It seems like something is wrong with inheritance and I am just not understanding what I am doing wrong.

Comment: this should not even compile `try { /*some code*/ }  /*some code*/ catch (Exception e) {}`

Comment: @Selvin I will appreciate if you can explain to me what i am doing wrong. I am new to both java and android studio

Answer (score 0):

```
   try {
      String timeVal = String.valueOf(time);
      FileOutputStream timeStream = openFileOutput("time_file.txt",    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    timeStream.write(timeVal.getBytes());
}
    timeStream.close();
   catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Your code will compile if you write:

```
 try {
  String timeVal = String.valueOf(time);
  FileOutputStream timeStream = openFileOutput("time_file.txt",    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      timeStream.write(timeVal.getBytes());
      timeStream.close();
     }catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If think this sytanx is wrong, does this code compile ?
Please read this, I know, long but you have to study now or later:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

same
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm

if you write file to the external storge, mind to add the READ and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest